# what's wrong with the counters in sorting functions

Tags: c++, sorting, counter

in my program there are two sorting functions shaker and shell sorting functions, also in each sorting there are two  counters, a count of the number of permutations and count of the number of comparisons, but for some reason they do not work, I just can’t understand why, I will be grateful for any help =)

```
void ShakerSort(ZKR* M, int N) {
    int l, r, i, k, buf;
    int q = 0;
    int g = 0;
    k = l = 0;
    r = N - 2;
    while(l <= r) {
        for(i = l; i <= r; i++)

            if(M[i].ACADEMIC_DEGREE > M[i + 1].ACADEMIC_DEGREE) {
                q++;
                buf = M[i].ACADEMIC_DEGREE;
                M[i].ACADEMIC_DEGREE = M[i + 1].ACADEMIC_DEGREE;
                M[i + 1].ACADEMIC_DEGREE = buf;

                k = i;
            }
        g++;
        r = k - 1;
        for(i = r; i >= l; i--)

            if(M[i].ACADEMIC_DEGREE > M[i + 1].ACADEMIC_DEGREE) {
                q++;
                buf = M[i].ACADEMIC_DEGREE;
                M[i].ACADEMIC_DEGREE = M[i + 1].ACADEMIC_DEGREE;
                M[i + 1].ACADEMIC_DEGREE = buf;

                k = i;
            }
        g++;

        l = k + 1;
    }
    cout << "Number of comparisons = " << q << endl;
    cout << "Number of permutations = " << g << endl;
}

//                                                 SHELL SORT
void sortShell(ZKR* M, int N) {
    int g = 0;
    int q = 0;
    int t = clock();
    int step = N / 2;
    while(step > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < (N - step); ++i) {
            q++;
            int j = i;
            while((j >= 0) && (M[j].ACADEMIC_DEGREE > M[j + step].ACADEMIC_DEGREE)) {
                int tmp = M[j].ACADEMIC_DEGREE;
                M[j].ACADEMIC_DEGREE = M[j + step].ACADEMIC_DEGREE;
                M[j + step].ACADEMIC_DEGREE = tmp;
                j -= step;
                g++;
            }
        }
        step /= 2;
    }
    cout << "Number of comparisons = " << q << endl;
    cout << "Number of permutations = " << g << endl;
    cout << "Время  сортировки  = " << clock() - t << "мили cекунд" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "they do not work".

Comment: Also, make a [mcve]. We can't compile what you show.

Comment: Please provide the error msg, not very clear about "for some reason they do not work".

Comment: Also make use of better variable names, why use `q` and `g` for comparisons and permutations? Why not just use `comparisons` and `permutations` it makes your code so much easier to read